# Why am I seeing "server_audit: logging was flushed." in my AWS Aurora RDS logs?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

We started seeing on our RDS cluster errors like the one below:

```
190520 9:00:00 server_audit: logging was flushed.
```

However, we do not understand the severity of this issue or if any actions are required by our side to fix this?

Since this is showing up on our production account, it is triggering our automated alerts and started notifying our admins for the last few hours :-(.

Comment: This particular incident occurred at a "suspiciously round number" timestamp.  What is the interval at which these are occurring?

Comment: They happen every 30 mins, exactly, like clockwork.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS support claims that this error is innocuous and they're working on a fix.  Unfortunately, they've been working on that fix for ~2 months now with nothing to show for it.

Comment: December 2020, hope it's still innocuous ... :D

Comment: This is fixed in the latest Aurora MySQL RDS version. It doesn't happen for me anymore.